# raw_input with Main thread and concurrent thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working on a Python scripts that kicks off a thread with a loop and a raw_input so that user can enter commands. After this thread starts, main program starts a loop with another raw_input so that the user can enter commands.

How can this be organized so that the commands being inputted via console goes to the correct raw_input (main thread/concurrent thread)? At the moment, all inputs in the console are going to the main thread only.

Thanks

**Example**

```
import threading

def commThread():
    while True:
        chatAcceptance = raw_input("User")


t1 = threading.Thread(target=commThread)
t1.start()

while True:
    userInput = raw_input("\nPlease insert a command:\n")
```

Comment: In the general case, this question is nonsensical: you clearly *don't* want the user to be typing responses to two different threads at the same time (what would that even mean)? The only way it could possibly work is if you limited the cases where another thread could "own" the console for a while. But a much better approach to this problem would be to have a dedicated console I/O thread, which would only handle interactions, and would communicate with other threads the results of those interactions. (This is how GUI toolkits for most operating systems work, for example.)

Comment: Not sure what you really want, your code works as expected here.

Answer (score 0):

So this can be done via lock. I did a small code example that shows how to swap between one "scope" to the other using the raw_input.

```
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

def inputReader(thread, prompt):
    userInput = raw_input(prompt)
    print thread + " " + userInput + "\n"
    return userInput


def myThread1():
    global lock

    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        print "thread 1 got the lock\n"
        while True:
            threadInput = inputReader("thread 1", "from thread 1\n")
            if threadInput == "release":
                lock.release()
                print "thread 1 released the lock\n"
                break


def myThread2():
    global lock

    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        print "thread 2 got the lock\n"
        while True:
            threadInput = inputReader("thread 2", "from thread 2\n")
            if threadInput == "release":
                lock.release()
                print "thread 2 released the lock\n"
                break


t1 = threading.Thread(target=myThread1).start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=myThread2).start()
```